# Windows 8 tablet - How to prevent explorer from starting desktop app with maximized window?

Tags: windows-8, explorer

When I start a desktop application on Windows 8 tablet, Explorer starts it with SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED.
For example, if you start Notepad from command prompt, it opens in normal window size, but if you do that from Explorer, maximized window is opened.  I have seen this Explorer behavior only on tablet PC and I guess Explorer is doing that on purpose.

I understand that it may be useful for many application programs, but I want my program to start with normal size unless user explicitly requests Explorer to open it maximized.

Is there a way to stop this for my application?  I'm hoping that there is an API or manifest to do that, but I couldn't find any information at MSDN.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you realize that your program is free to ignore SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED?

Comment: Yes.  But, I also want to start my program with maximized window If user wants to do so (by setting shortcut option, etc).

Comment: In this thread, someone seems to have the same issue. It might be, however weird it may sound, a driver issue: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/173349-windows-81-maximize/?p=1093262

Comment: And here's a similar question asked on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930582/how-to-stop-explorer-starting-my-application-maximized -- One of the comments is by Raymond Chen and he gives a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

1. **Open** any program that is affected with this issue. *Note: Make sure that it is the only open window of that program. eg. You can only do this if you have one window of command prompt open.*
2. **Adjust** the window size and position to your liking.
3. While holding *Ctrl* on your keyboard, **close** the window by clicking (or touching, for tablet) the *X* in the top-right corner of the window to close it.
4. **Re-open** the program. Your window should now open in the way you set it in step 3.

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter key by mistake....   As I wrote in my original question, Explorer starts the program SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED on tablet PC even after doing what you suggested.  It only works on non-tablet PC, where Explorer starts application with SW_SHOWNORMAL.

Comment: What other programs have this issue? All desktop programs? Only programs when launched from the desktop? Only Microsoft programs? Does cmd open maximized?

Comment: See if manually running the .exe from C:\Program Files\[Program] will open normally from Explorer (not in cmd).

Comment: Done that, no difference.  Are you actually seeing different result?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not a question about each program remembering its window size.  It's about Explorer always starting desktop application with SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED on Windows 8 tablet.  I'm not sure if it happens with all Windows 8 tablets, but I'm seeing this with HP Stream 7.  As I wrote in my original question, it doesn't happen when the program is started from command prompt.  So, I'm pretty sure that it's Explorer's behavior.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that maybe your desktop shortcuts had an additional flag for SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED, but I'm looking into this issue. We know it is obviously something with Explorer, of course.