# Why my installer in tablet mode has a different behavior in PC?

Tags: nsis

I wrote a installer with nsis and it has two different behaviors. When is running at PC the installer's window isn't maximize,however in tablet mode the installer runs in full screen. Is possible make the installer not run in full screen at tablet pc?

Comment: Is the same case as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930582/how-to-stop-explorer-starting-my-application-maximized

Comment: Is this Windows 8, 8.1 or 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS creates a dialog without a maximize button and does not expect Windows to maximize the window.

I agree with the comment posted by Francisco R, this is a undocumented Windows behavior and as noted in the comments on the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930582/how-to-stop-explorer-starting-my-application-maximized#comment46144220_28930582), a bug in Windows that it will maximize windows without a maximize button.